# Google Sheets App Script to fill out a form

Tags: named-ranges

I have a spreadsheet with two tabs, "Service Requests" and "CC".

Service requests have multiple lines of various customers and info.
CC is a blank form that I want to fill out based on the active line in Service Requests
I have named ranges in the CC tab.

I have this working fine in Excel, what I'm used to , but need it to work in sheets.
I'm new to App Scripts.

This is what I have so far just trying to get one cell to copy but doesn't work.

````
```    function FillOutForm(){
```    var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```    var SR = spreadsheetDocument.getSheetByName('Service Requests');
```    var CC = spreadsheetDocument.getSheetByName('CC')();
```    var rangeToCopy = SR.getActiveRange();
```    rangeToCopy.copyTo(CC.getRange('Name'));
```    }
````

The named ranges I have on CC are Address, Date, Name, Notes, Phone, Town, WifiName, WifiPassword

I'd like to fill these out from the activecell on service requests and then each cell offset to the right of the activecell for the other fields.

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: 1st tab is Service requests. Looks like this:
Name Ticket # Phone Address System System Ours? Y/N
John Doe 20657 555-123-1234 101 here Goodwe Y
Jane Doe 30001 555-123-1234 102 there SMA Y
Harry 20620 555-123-1234 103 everywhere  n


Second tab is CC:  Its a blank form for a printout of the service ticket. I have named ranges on it and would like to fill in NAME TICKET #, Phone Address etc on the blank form.
Sorry formatting is no translating well and I cant add a screen shot.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No problem, I speak English and I am having trouble explaining it also. :-)
It would be nice if I could attach a file here.

Comment: Ok, let me try this way.  Tab1 has row 1 column A as "Name1", Row 1 Col B has "Address1"
row 2 -10 have the same thing but progress with Name 2, 3, 4 etc and Address 2, 3, 4 etc.
On Tab2  I have a named cell Called "Name" and a named cell called "Address"

What I want the macro to do is fill in the named cells on tab2 from whichever row I happen to be on in Tab1.

So if I am on row 3 of tab one and click on the macro then Tab2 Named cell "Name" would equal "Name3" and Tab2 Named cell "Address" would equal "Address 3"

Hope that makes sense...
Thanks.